# Segmentation fault when calling a member function using a derived pointer

Tags: c++, c++17

Can anyone tell me why calling `d->method1()` in the code below leads to a segmentation fault in c++?

```
class Base{
    public:
        virtual void method1() {}
        void method2() {}
};
class Derived : public Base{
    public:
        Derived() {}
        void method1() {}  
        void method2() {}   
};

int main () {
   Base *b = dynamic_cast<Base *>(new Derived()); 
   Derived *d = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(new Base());

   b->method1(); // derived
   d->method2(); // derived
   d->method1(); // --> segmentation fault. why?
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `d` is null. `new Base()` doesn't point to an instance of `Dervied`, and so `dynamic_cast` produces a null pointer. Naturally, a call through a null pointer exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

When using `dynamic_cast<...>`, it returns a null pointer if the cast fails, so make sure you check the result before using it, eg:

```
if (d = dynamic_cast<DestType>(someVariable))
{
    // here you can use d
    // dynamic cast succeeded
}
```

Comment: Minor point: `dynamic_cast` to a **pointer** type returns a null pointer if the cast fails. `dynamic_cast` to a **reference** type throws a `std::bad_cast` exception if the cast fails. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a base class into a derived class, so your 'd' pointer is NULL.[image: null pointer]

Comment: You CAN cast a pointer to a base class into a pointer to a derived class, but only if the pointer is pointing at a derived object. Maybe that is what you were trying to say, but that is not made clear in your answer.